# Triggering 2 tabs with one click

Tags: javascript, onclick

I found 'one click triggers 2' but it doesn't seem to be what I am wanting - perhaps only because the one click is changing 2 slides not tabs.  I want one click to switch tabs on 2 tab sets.  My tabs are called tab1,2,and 3 and legendtab1,2, and 3.
I am only testing from the legendtabx set and have `<div class="tabbable">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('legendtab1').onclick , document.getElementById('tab1').onclick = function() {
        <a href="#legendtab1" data-toggle="tab")Standard</a>;
        <a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab")Standard</a>;
document.getElementById('legendtab2').onclick, document.getElementById('tab2').onclick = function()  {
        <a href="#legendtab2" data-toggle="tab")Sprint</a>;
        <a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab")Sprint</a>
document.getElementById('legendtab3').onclick, document.getElementById('tab3').onclick= function() {
        <a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab")Ski</a>
        <a href="#legendtab3" data-toggle="tab")Ski</a>;
}
</script>`
This results in, in each case, triggers the tabx tabs but not the legendtabx.  strangely even though in the case of tab3 the hrefs are in the reverse order,  As you can likely tell, I am not a strong js programmer but I think it is js that should be able to do the job. 
 A little bit about why this need.  It is a Joomla site and on the main content are 3 tabs with  information about each of 3 types of events.  In the module we show the symbols associated with each of the 3 types of events.  So, when a visitor looks at the ski info on one area, I want the other area to display the related info about skiing.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to end your function's with ending }'s. You were also not assigning your onclick function correctly for the 'legendtab' onclicks. This may work better for you.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var switchTab1 = function() {
    <a href="#legendtab1" data-toggle="tab")Standard</a>;
    <a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab")Standard</a>;
}
var switchTab2 = function() {
    <a href="#legendtab2" data-toggle="tab")Sprint</a>;
    <a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab")Sprint</a>
}
var switchTab3 = function() {
    <a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab")Ski</a>
    <a href="#legendtab3" data-toggle="tab")Ski</a>;
}

document.getElementById('legendtab1').onclick = switchTab1;
document.getElementById('tab1').onclick = switchTab1;

document.getElementById('legendtab2').onclick = switchTab2;
document.getElementById('tab2').onclick = switchTab2;

document.getElementById('legendtab3').onclick = switchTab3;
document.getElementById('tab3').onclick = switchTab3;

</script>
```